# simple html dom parser and <span>

Tags: html-parsing

I hope anyone can help me with this.

I have an html code like this:

```html
<div id="v4-95"><div id="v4-96" class="pview rs-pview"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2" class="grid"><tr><td width="33%" class="gallery"><a name="item19c368bcd6"></a><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="10" class="gallery"><tr><td class="picture camera" width="100%" height="140"><div class="image" style="width: 140px;"><a href="http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/SAMSUNG-LTN156AT02-15-6-LAPTOP-SCREEN-NEW-/110652603606?pt=UK_Computing_LaptopAccess_RL&amp;hash=item19c368bcd6" class="gpvi" id="src110652603606" _sp="p4634.c0.m14.l1262" r="1"><img alt="Item image" title="Item image" src="http://thumbs3.ebaystatic.com/m/mvOLm6Tv8Lid54uveSlY80A/140.jpg" border="0"></a></div></td></tr><tr><td><div class="mi"></div></td></tr><tr><td class="details"><div class="ttl g-std"><a id="src110652603606" _sp="p4634.c0.m14.l1262" r="1" href="http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/SAMSUNG-LTN156AT02-15-6-LAPTOP-SCREEN-NEW-/110652603606?pt=UK_Computing_LaptopAccess_RL&amp;hash=item19c368bcd6" target="_parent" title="SAMSUNG LTN156AT02 15.6&quot; LAPTOP SCREEN NEW">SAMSUNG LTN156AT02 15.6" LAPTOP SCREEN NEW</a><img src="http://q.ebaystatic.com/aw/pics/s.gif" width="16" alt="This seller accepts PayPal" height="16" class="ii iippl"></div><div><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="fixed"><tr><td><img src="http://q.ebaystatic.com/aw/pics/bin_15x54.gif" alt="Buy It Now" title="Buy It Now"></td><td><span class="bin g-b">£41.50</span></td></tr>
```

I can retrive the title with this code:

```php
 $html = file_get_html('http://stores.ebay.co.uk/LCD-Kings/15-6-/_i.html?_fsub=886314010&_sid=73271570&_trksid=p4634.c0.m322');
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) 
echo $element->title . '<br>';
```

But I don't understand how can I retrieve the £41,50 between the span and why it has a space in the class "bin gb"...

thanks for help...

Answer (score 1):

It has a space in the class because that element has two classes. One is called `bin`, the other is called `g-b`. I'm guessing `g-b` refers to Great Britain so the price may be the span that has the class `bin`.

You haven't provided all the HTML but there may be an outer element that you can search for (such as: a div with id `product` and then, within that, find the price in the span with class `bin`).

You should lookup the documentation of your DOM parser and see what arguments it supports for `find()`. If it supports something like `#product span.bin` (or similar syntax) then you can select the `span` with that class.

Comment: I update the html code to see whole in previous post... I see an id like you said..

Comment: Thanks, after test it works with this code:

foreach($html->find('.bin') as $element)
    echo $element->plaintext . '<br />';